# How to run ngnix as non root user in redhat

Tags: nginx, redhat

I am already running ngnix as root user in my redhat server. but I want to run ngnix as non root user now because of some security concerns.

Please help me to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

youll need an user `nginx` with the specified rights or you use the existing group `www-data`. In either your service or your upstart file you need to specifie the user .

**service / init**
 use `sudo -u <username> <cmd>`

**systemd / upstart**
There are options like group=

But we will need more informations about your system. is there alrady a service file? A redhat version number? Can you post your service file